# How to get multi-return values in Solidity?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-deployment

I wanna know how to get multiple return values from function in Solidity
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Solidity was old method to get multi-return values from function through keyword `var` but is was deprecated in 0.5.0 if i'm not mistake

Solidity allows functions to return multiple values. Here is an example to demonstrate this:

```
{ 
    function a() returns (int a, string b) 
    { 
        return (1, "Hello"); 
    } 

    function b() 
    { 
        int A; 
        string memory B; 

        //A is 1 and B is "Hello" 
        (A, B) = a(); 

        //A is 1 
        (A,) = a(); 

        //B is "Hello" 
        (, B) = a(); 
    } 
}
```